# How to enable support for synonyms in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, synonym

We have implemented Elastic Search for a web app. The search works well for the most part, except it does not understand synonyms. We have followed the instruction from:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html.

But we still couldn't make the synonym search work.

Can someone provide more detailed instructions?

Thanks.

Comment: i had some path issues when first implementing it. try the absolute path and look into the es logs. try with creating new indexes first.

Comment: Maybe start with the important part of the mapping and the query you try to execute. Than we can have a better look.